# How to open and edit an excel template using visual basic

Tags: excel, visual-studio, vba, excel-template

I have a template that we use at work that I want to edit using visual basic. I have a gui built that asks the user for a few pieces of data. I need to open the template and just edit the contents of the template based on the user input. I have done research so far and everything I've seen shows me how to open a new excel document, not a current one. How do I open the current template?

*I get the user to browse for and select the filename and have that stored as a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say what you want to achieve maybe more clarification is needed.

**To reference an Opened Excel file**

```
Set execlObj = GetObject(fileName)
```

**To open an Unopened Excel file (in separate Excel application)**

```
Dim oXLApp As Object, wb As Object
Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
```

Where file name is e.g. c:\test.xls

Comment: On the right track... wouldn't I need to open the excel application first?

Comment: See updated answer if you are looking to open the Excel in a separate process (separate Excel application). You can just as well open in in the current Excel process.

Comment: Ok, I think I was getting hung up on the CreateObject as opening/creating a new blank excel document.

Comment: CreateObject is a command to create an object of a certain type (in this case a separate Excel process application). You may just as well declare oXLApp as Excel.Application and define it by Set oXLApp = new Excel.Application. Please mark post as answer if correct